# How do i capture each time the Operating System OR the Active Window is busy

Tags: windows, cursor, system, interrupt

I am trying to capture Windows system busy, or Active window busy, from the perspective of the end user (typically when the Windows OS or the active Window puts up a Busy Cursor: or to capture when the system is busy).    I am trying to do this without having to continually use GetCursor.   Is there any way to set up a windows interrupt, such that when the Operating System or the the active Window is busy that and interrupt can be generated?   thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could perform monitoring of the ProcessorQueueLength using the [Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394272%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) WMI object. There are various other performance counter, use the perfmon tool to investigate which of these are most useful to you.